# Enzyme + React: Testing user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme

So I'm pretty new to writing tests and React. It doesn't help that the enzyme documentation is only so helpful.

I have an `<input>` element inside a `<form>` and when the element has focus and there is no text inside of the `<input>`, a `<div>` is created underneath the `<input>` with the text `Required`. Once the user starts typing into the `<input>`, the text is supposed to change to `Make sure your code is correct`.

I can simulate the user giving the `<input>` focus and trying to submit a blank form. Where I am having trouble is simulating user input into the `<input>` so that the text changes from `Required` to `Make sure your code is correct`. Using this bit of code I've written, the text inside of the `text-danger` `<div>` remains `Required`. Maybe I am not simulating the user pressing the `a` key correctly, I'm not really sure.

So to reiterate what I want to happen:

- User clicks on the `<input>` element
- User types a character (such as `a` in this example)
- the `<div>` underneath `<input>` has the text `Make sure your code is correct`

Test

```
  it('should render correct <div> element', () => {
    component.find('input').simulate('blur');
    component.find('input').simulate('keyDown', { key: 'a' });

    expect(component.find('.text-danger').exists()).to.be.true;
    expect(component.find('.text-danger').name()).to.equal('div');
    expect(component.find('strong').text()).to.not.equal('Required');
  });
```

Comment: You can try `component.find('input').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'a'}});` Let me know if it works. In case it doesn't work you can try `component.find('input').simulate('input', { target: { value: 'a' } });`

Comment: @Dekel I appreciate the suggestions but neither of these are working. When using `change` I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. When using `input` the wrong `<div>` is rendered. On a side note, if I ONLY simulate a `blur`, and no `keyDown`/`input`/`change` the `<div>` with the text of `Required` is automatically rendered. Maybe there's a problem with using `blur` in this situation?

Comment: It might be relevant to the fact that the `input` is `blured` and not `focused` :) Can you try to add `component.find('input').simulate('focus');` between the two `simulate` lines?

Comment: I added in the `simulate('focus')` into the mix and still nothing. I don't know if this changes anything but the form has to actually be submitted with the incorrect registration code to show the div I want. So I've added a `simulate('submit')`. Still giving me the wrong text.